# $request->input always return null

Tags: angularjs, laravel

angularjs file

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: API_URL + "produto/update" + "/" + produtoSelecionado,
    data: $.param(obj),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).success(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert(response);
    location.reload();
}).error(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert('An error has occured. Please check the log for details.');
});
location.reload();
```

php controller:

```
public function decreaseQuantity(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::table('product') ->where('id', $id) -> decrement('quantity',$request->input('quantity')); 
}
```

It gives me this error all the time, even if i pass a specific value of quantity.

[image: Error message]

I check the variable `obj` to see if it there was a problem with it but its fine, the value is there. The strange thing is that i have exactly other function that does the same but instead of decrement, increment and it works fine, just this one doenst and i dont know why

Comment: What is the value of `$.param(obj)`?

Comment: Using your Web Browser's Network Inspector tab, do you see the outgoing request with the data as expected?

Comment: `dd()` your Request in controller and take a look. Error description tells you a problem. So *quantity* isn't a number.